# Why is Chrome freezing?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Google Chrome´s rendering area is constantly freezing in my computer. Not the whole software, only it´s rendering area. Clicks are still working, mouse pointer still changes when hovering some link. Even if I click on a link it seems that it is loaded, the url changes and etc.

There are some sites that are suspect of having content that causes this behaviour. Coincidently (or not) they are javascript loaded sites:

- Gmail
- Google Docs

What I have already tried:

- Disable all plugins
- Reinstall Google Chrome

What makes it unfreeze:

- Resize the entire window. It seems to me that for some reason Chrome stops refreshing until a resize happens.
- Killing GPU process unfreezes all tabs.
- In a new tab load one of the suspect sites

Relevant versions

- Chrome Version `24.0.1312.52 m` (but it was happening before update)
- Windows 7

My questions

- Any idea on what could cause this?
- Is there any debugging level log that I could enable (GPU process only would be perfect) so I can see what has happened just before the freezing?

Comment: More information is required. This actually sounds like a problem I had that turned out to be caused by a failing hdd.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, what kind of additional information should I provide? Thanks.

Comment: For instance you mention it crashed, more information about the crash, might be helpful.

Comment: Changed the word crashes for freezes and added more info on it.

Comment: Are you able to verify if Firefox present similar problems as Chrome?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it does not freeze at all in Firefox. Neither safari. And, believe me, not even IE. But I like chrome way too much to let it go easily :-)

Comment: Are there a Lot of Extension or Add-on ? Did you had a look at Task Manager in Chrome ? (While in Chrome Press `Shift`+`Esc`) try ending some of the processes in there, Does it help ?

Comment: +1 @Lamb. With a tab frozen, in Chrome´s Task Manager I could see a GPU process consuming a lot of memory, wich raised my attention. Killing that process made it unfreeze, just like when resizing the window. Will add more info in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible it's flash/html5 video which is offloading to your GPU for processing? To test, does it freeze on text-only, no ads sites?

Comment: @LuckySpoon, I still can´t determine that. It is not flash for sure, it has frozen some times with flash completely disabled. I do notice it happening more frequently when gmail is opened.

Comment: Have you tried updating your video card drivers?

Comment: @NathanAdams Good idea, will try it and post the results as soon as possible.

Comment: I Think I have one to charge here... http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-catalyst/pages/catalyst.aspx

Comment: Was Unity Player plugin related for me..

Answer (score 8):

It is a bug of GPU acceleration. You can disable it in chrome command line. 
Add these parameters in chrome command line.
 --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer

Comment: This one worked for me.

Comment: --disable-gpu was enough on my system (Linux 64bit).

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem with the same symptoms. The fix on [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/103292/how-to-fix-shockwave-flash-crashes-in-google-chrome/) did it for me.

To summarise:

1. Type in about:plugins into the address bar.
2. Press the Details + button at the top right of the list.
3. Find Adobe Flash Player on the list. There should be two files under
   that entry.
4. For the entry under Chrome e.g found at
   `C:\Users\(User)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\....`click
   **Disable**.
5. Restart Google Chrome.

Although this worked for me, I can't be sure it will for you. I hope it does, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I too was having a similar problem with Chrome. I was able to fix it by stopping the following services.

- McAfee HIPSCore Service
- McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention Service

Once these services were stopped, chrome.exe was removed from Task Manager and then I was able to restart Chrome.

Here's the [link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/zgyq-4yKpcQ/JZhAAnWg0YsJ) to the Google Product Forums post.

I hope this helps someone else too!