# How can I find out why Chrome is freezing my computer?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, google-chrome, freeze

My system keeps hanging. The image shown below shows Chrome process 5660 as active while my disk utilization is peaked. During this time my computer seems to freeze. I can't open a new tab, can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, I can't even <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then after 55 seconds or so, it seems whatever process that was causing my computer to hang times out and everything begins to work normally.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

It's easily reproducible, basically I'm checking out [this map](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B92I26nDotirWHVMekN4a2VhOHM/edit), and as I zoom in and out, the system goes into a hanging state. It's mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/535959/why-is-chrome-freezing) that I can use arguments to disable GPU involvement (I'm not sure if it's GPU related though. Process explorer reported minimal GPU usage during these freezes). But I would rather dig a little deeper to see if I can find a direct cause. Perhaps a specific process, service or driver that is causing this, so it can be forwarded to the appropriate company.

What else can I do to better identify this situation?

Comment: Also, I understand it may not be chrome that is causing my system to hang, but the service/process that is causing chrome and my system to hang.

And it's not my hard drive, because this has happened on 3 of my hard drives.

Comment: did you turn off extensions in chrome?

Comment: Yes. Still happens :\

Comment: chrome://flags  
Check for known conflicts with 3rd party modules  
Play with gpu/software rendering WebGl D3d other graphics settings

Comment: Ok. But my original question is about how to find what process, service or driver is involved with the disk utilization spike, not how to keep it from happening.

Comment: its not the browser, its a plugin/ext/activex/etc... that causes the problems. Does it happen on certain websites? http://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off

Comment: How much memory does your system have and how much is used/free when this happens? Are any of the `chrome.exe` instances using a lot of memory when it happens?

Comment: temporary stop the **Superfetch** service in Windows and look if this fixes it.

Comment: Ok, again. Like I originally said to begin with. "I understand it may not be chrome thats causing my system to hang". I'll now go back to asking, again.

Comment: How can I find what processes, services or drivers are involved while my system is hanging? Is there a way to see what process service or driver is using up my disk during that time? 

Or how bout, "Is there an android "logcat" equivalent for windows 7?"

Comment: Probably java. !